# Should JPA be part of EJB Module and/or Web Module in a Eclipse Enterprise Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am working on Java 1.6. The application server is JBoss 5.0. I am using Eclipse Kepler.

In Eclipse I create a new *Enterprise Application Project (EAR Application Project)* by selecting File --> New --> Enterprise Application Project. I name it **MyApp**.

I selected it to have 2 modules: 
1) *EJB Module* (I call it **MyAppEJB**) 
2) *Web Module* (I call it **MyAppWeb**)

Now how to include JPA? Eclipse is giving me choice to include JPA in **MyAppEJB** and/or **MyAppWeb**.

Q1: Should JPA be part of **MyAppEJB** only?

Q2: Should JPA be part of **MyAppWeb** only?

Q3: Should JPA be part of both **MyAppEJB** and **MyAppWeb**?

What I am trying to understand is that in which project I would put my JPA stuff (entities, DAOs, etc.). In EJB project or Web project?

Comment: As far as I understand you have **MyAppWeb** (service layer containing, i.e. REST API for external clients) and **MyAppEJB** (business layer). It would be more reasonable to put JPA stuff in **MyAppEJB**. You may also consider to add, i.e. **MyAppDAO** (data access layer) with an exclusive access to the entities. So the dependencies would look like this MyAppWeb --knows--> MyAppEJB --knows-->MyAppDAO

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Design.

If your web application also need to communicate to database then you can include it in web module too.

`JPA` is an Independent standard to perform DB operations and it is not tied to `EJB` like '`Entity Beans`' were.

Comment: where I am going to put all my JPA stuff? like JPA entities, JPA DAOs etc.? in EJB project or Web project?

Comment: If you do DB operations only in EJB module, then keep it over there, and if you do in both places, then create a common project for JPA and let each module depend on it.

Comment: I would do DB operations only in EJB module so it makes sense to have it in EJB module only. Now the JSPs will be in Web module and would not I be passing the entities to the JSP for display? How will this workout?

Comment: Keep your entity objects and EJB Data transfer objects separate. So you copy the data from entity objects to DTO when you return result back from EJB or Web Service interface.

Comment: So the JSPs will only know about the DTOs and dont know about entities? Then should not the DAOs return DTOs instead of entities? or build DTOs from entities in EJBs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77212/discussion-between-chumbochappati-and-k139).